# Zend PHP, porting from Linux to Windows -> setting baseUrl

Tags: php, zend-framework, iis, base-url

Recently I was tasked with porting a PHP website, built on Zend, from an Arch Linux server to a Windows server.  I have no experience with PHP.  I pulled all the files back and tried bringing it up on IIS with PHP and CGI installed, to no effect.  After changing some /'s to \'s in the pathing, I was still having issues and installed Zend studio.

I stepped through the page and found that the following bit, which seems off:

```
$baseUrl = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '/index.php'));
$front_controller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front_controller->setBaseUrl($baseUrl);
```

When I debug the page, I find that $baseUrl is being set to (string:0).  If I comment out this line and the line that set the base url of the front controller the page will actually load and displays the login page; however, images an links from that page don't appear to work correctly.  If I hard set $baseUrl to '/index.php', the login page also loads, but when I try to interact with it, it recursively adds '/index.php' to the URL until the browser dies.

I've searched google, and these forums, to try to determine what this actually needs to be set to.  When I look at the PHP_SELF property of $_SERVER in the debugger, it is

```
(string:90) C:\Users\[userid]\AppData\Local\Temp\dummy.phpC:\Users\[userid]\AppData\Local\Temp\dummy.php
```

The page being hosted on IIS is currently under C:\WEBPAGE\ctcAB.

I've tried a variety of things including the windows path with \'s and /'s, .\ctcAB, .\ctcAB\index.php, and a number of permutations of the URL I get in the browser, both with and without http:// (which, from what I've read, I understand to be incorrect.).

**So, when running a Zend PHP page on IIS on Windows, what does one need to set the base url of the Zend_Controller_Front to be?**  Is it relative to the file path that IIS is pointing to?  Is it relative to the URL displayed at the root?

I saw another suggestion to get the baseUrl from $this; however, when I try that, I'm informed by the debugger that $this isn't in context.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you don't need to change `/` to ``\`` in Windows-based PHP code. PHP will auto-convert `/` to the native OS separators for you. In fact, it's better if you ALWAYS use `/`, because ``\`` becomes a royal pain in the rump once you start using it in strings. `$path = 'C:\\Blah\\blah\\blah'` just gets... ugly.

Comment: You don't normally need to manually set the base URL - is there a reason you think you need to for this app?

Comment: Tim, unfortunately I don't know enough about PHP to know.  The initial code that evaluates to 'string(0)' while debugging was part of the (working) application when I forklifted it out of it's home linux server.  I've been focusing on this as a potential source of broken links to images, css files, and inoperable post commands.  I don't know if that's accurate or not, but all the pathing appears to be in place, so I'm unsure of what else I should be looking at.

Comment: Okay, after some digging, I believe I have confirmed that the lack of a baseUrl being defined is the issue which is breaking the subsequent page loads.  Looking at the header.phtml file loaded by the logon page, I found a number of items like this <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl; ?>/public/styles/screen.css" />.  If the baseUrl isn't accurately defined, it prevents everything from loading.